# Почему не выдаёт ошибку компиляции? Системы счисления

Tags: java, float, системы-счисления, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Т. е. автор этих строк говоря о том, что данное число "просто не влезет" в тип float, говорит о том, что его точность будет потеряна?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 123456789.65656565656565f;
    }
}
```

Простой код. Объявляем и инициализируем переменную f типа float. Её представление в двоичном виде: 11101011011110011010001010110101000000. Т.е. 38 цифр, значит под это число потребуется 38 бит, а у типа float их всего 32. Соответственно вопрос: почему код компилируется без ошибки?

Comment: Потому что компилятор знает, что не все числа, которые вводит программист, он может представить (к примеру, 1/3) и округляет до ближайшего удобного (представимого числа).

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 123456789.65656565656565f;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", f));
  }

Answer (score 1):

Потому что компилятор округляет по стандарту [IEEE-754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

> Стандарт определяет пять правил округления. Первые два правила
> округляют к ближайшему значению, другие называются направленными округлениями.
>
> **Округление к ближайшему**
>
> - Округление к ближайшему (привязка к четному). Если два ближайших числа с плавающей точкой одинаково близки, то должно быть получено
>   число с чётной самой младшей цифрой. Это вариант по умолчанию для
>   двоичной плавающей запятой и рекомендованный вариант по умолчанию для
>   десятичного числа.
> - Округление к ближайшему (привязка к бесконечности). Если два ближайших числа с плавающей точкой одинаково близки, то должно быть
>   получено число с большим модулем.
>
> **Направленные округления**
>
> - Округление к 0 - направленное округление к нулю (также известное как усечение).
> - Округление к + ∞ - направленное округление к положительной бесконечности (также известное как округление вверх или потолок).
> - Округление к - ∞ - направленное округление к отрицательной бесконечности (также известное как округление вниз или пол).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 123456789.65656565656565f;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", f));
    // 123456792.00000
  }
```

PS. А так существует в Java BigDecimal который даст вам хранить в привычном вам виде.

Answer (score 0):

Java не накладывает ограничений на длину дробной части. Это [формальный ответ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Слишком длинные дроби округляются. Компилятор не выдаёт предупреждение, потому что и короткие дроби округляются: например `0.1` не представимо точно в виде двоичной дроби.

Это проблема не языка, а формата для хранения вещественных чисел. Невозможно представить все десятичные дроби в двоичном виде точно, поэтому терпим округления, поэтому компилятор не выдаёт предупреждения о заведомо излишних цифрах в литералах.